# Disable or hide options in combo box VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a combo box in a Excel Userform that consist of User Group Types.
Depending on the user access level, I would like to have some Option\item disable or not visible.
**I don't want to use Removeitem,** Because I would have to repopulate the list every time!

```
sub ComboBox_Enter() 

accessLvl = 1

ComboBox.AddItem "0-Show"
ComboBox.AddItem "1-Hide or disable"
ComboBox.AddItem "2-Show"
ComboBox.AddItem "3-Show"

For i = 0 To 3
      if accessLvl = 1 Then ComboBox.List(1).Hidden = True ' This not does work!! ''
Next

End sub
```

*I just want it to be disabled\grayed* out or not visible but still in the Combobox list!*

Comment: Fall back position would be a 3rd party control from Telerik or another vendor. They might have such a thing but it would cost $$$.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't do that but there is an alternative. The user will not be able to select certain items (whichever you specify) even though it will be visible and not disabled.

For this try this code

```
Dim boolC As Boolean

'~~> Add Sample data
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.AddItem "Please Choose Again"

    For i = 1 To 10
        ComboBox1.AddItem i
    Next i
End Sub

'~~> This will not let the user select items in 2nd
'~~> 3rd and 4th items
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If Not boolC Then
        boolC = True
        Select Case ComboBox1.ListIndex
            Case 1, 2, 3: ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0
        End Select
        boolC = False
    End If
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

Let's say your form looks like this on form start up.

[image]

The moment you select the 2nd ,3rd or the 4th item, you will get `Please Choose Again`

[image]

Comment: Thank you it's a Great alternative!