# Combo Box with option that can only be selected programatically and not by the user in VBA Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a combobox that has a special requirement. It needs to have an item that can only be selected by the program (based on certain criteria detected) and cannot be selected by the user itself. Is there any way to do this in VBA Access?

I found  [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19402747/disable-or-hide-options-in-combo-box-vba-excel) but it is somewhat of a workaround which I will do if there is not a better alternative. What I want is for the option to not even be visible.

Comment: Why even make it a combobox if the user shouldn't access it or be able to change the value. Just use a TextBox and present the value you want displayed?

Comment: Well there are a variety of options the user can select. There is just this one that it cannot that the program has to detect. If this option were to be set, then it will be locked and can only be unset programatically.

Comment: I suppose I could add the item, select it immediately, then lock it. When it needs to be unset I can unlock it, set the value to the default, and remove the item from the combobox.

Comment: If you know that the program has to use a certain value, just ignore whatever value is in the combobox and use the value you need to use instead.

Comment: I do not want this one particular option to be visible from the drop down menu. It should just be automatically selected based on certain criteria of the form but in no way should the user be able to select it himself.

Comment: why should it be in the combo box then?

Comment: It sounds like you just want an `If` statement in your code - i.e. `If need_to_use_specific_value Then use_value = specific_value Else use_value = combobox.Value` (or something like that)

Comment: @jsotola It needs to be in the combo box because it is related to all the other items in the combo box. When this particular value is set, I want it to be "illegal" to try and select another value for the combobox.

Comment: @YowE3K Can I give a value that does not exist inside of the combobox? How would I make it a two column value?

Comment: does that mean that the combo box is disabled completely when the value is set?

Comment: Yeah the value is locked in

Comment: It would really help if you showed the code you are using that is making use of the combobox's value.

Comment: set the combobox `enabled` property to false to disable the combobox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to move business logic out of your forms. You need two functions for this task.

```
Function SelectAndLock(ByRef SelectPicker As ComboBox, Id As Long)

    Dim SQL_GET As String
    SQL_GET = "SELECT ID, Text From ComboBoxValues WHERE [ID] = " & Id

    SelectPicker.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
    SelectPicker.RowSource = SQL_GET
    SelectPicker.Value = Id
    SelectPicker.enabled = False

End Function

Function PopulateSelectPicker(ByRef SelectPicker As ComboBox)

    Dim SQL_GET As String
    SQL_GET = "SELECT ID, Text From ComboBoxValues WHERE [ID] not in (your system ids);"

    SelectPicker.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
    SelectPicker.RowSource = SQL_GET
    SelectPicker.Value = "" ' or null if your field is nullable
    SelectPicker.enabled = True

End Function
```

Now if your model has dedected the "system" condition, you would call

```
call SelectAndLock(SelectPicker,id)
```

Which would select the id that the system choses and locks the combobox.

any other condition or by default, simply call

```
call PopulateSelectPicker(SelectPicker)
```

Which would list all options except the system ids user shouldn't see.

**This is just a concept. Adapt it as you require.**

Answer (score 1):

You could add an "on change" event to the combo box. Lets say the option which can only be chosen programmatically is "Program only item". I have also assumed that you have a previous field in the form which we can move the focus back to. You haven't mentioned what the criteria for this option is so for arguments sake I will presume that the previous field has to be 1 not 0 (you will have to alter the if...then clause to suit your criteria).

```
private sub cbo_list_change()

if me.cbo_list.value "Program  only item" then
  if me.chk_previous.value = 0 then 
    msgbox "This item cannot be selected. Please select an alternative item", vbOKOnly
    me.cbo_list.value =""
    chk_previous.setFocus
  end if
end if

End sub
```

You will be able to use `me.cbo_list.value="program only option"` in a different event when the criteria is met.

Answer (score 0):

This situation seems very strange, and I would never want it in my app... but accepting for the moment that the approach desired is correct and good, and a solution is needed...

You can bind to the data source table field (since you're in MS Access I assume bound forms, though that's not guaranteed) via a hidden control (textbox, I'll assume) that we'll call txtYouNoSeeMe.

Let's refer to the value you want to let the system select (but not the user) as NoPickMe.

Now you need to give your user the ability to select "most options" -- set up that combobox (cboYesYouSeeMe) as necessary and leave it unbound. NoPickMe is not an option on that list.

Finally, you will sadly have to wrap some logic into handling AfterUpdate events for cboYesYouSeeMe. When you wish to permit the user to select an option in cboYesYouSeeMe, you need to then transport the value selected over to your HIDDEN bound control txtYouNoSeeMe. Do that in the AfterUpdate event.

When you wish to have the system pick that "hidden" value NoPickMe (that the user should not see) so be it... place that value into the hidden txtYouNoSeeMe. I have no idea what you're going want to display (in such cases) in cboYesYouSeeMe.

When the record saves, txtYouNoSeeMe drives the value saved to the database. If no database is involved, then just ignore my references to data binding.

This solution works, though I may have forgotten to explain a detail or two. Hopefully you get the idea.